# How to get current file name when running under ERT?

Tags: ert, testing

I have a set of tests that involve loading files from the file-system and I would like to use the current filename to locate the test files relative to the test file.

The below code shows the pattern I am trying, but unfortunately when I run the test using `M-x ert`, it fails with `(wrong-type-argument stringp nil)`, because both the `load-file-name` and `buffer-file-name` are `nil`. How should I approach this?

```
(ert-deftest closing-braces ()
  (find-file (concat (file-name-directory
                       (or load-file-name buffer-file-name))
                     "ClosingBrace.file"))
  ...
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wild guess: put the file name in a `defvar` or a `defconst`, and use it in the function:

```
(defconst my-test-location (file-name-directory (or load-file-name buffer-file-name)))

(ert-deftest closing-braces ()
  (find-file (concat my-test-location "ClosingBrace.file")))
```

What you want is the value of `load-file-name` or `buffer-file-name` at compile/load time, but when you reference it within your function (`ert-deftest` is a fancy version of `defun`), you get the value at run time, which is not as useful. With `defvar` or `defconst`, you should be able to "lock in" the compile/load time value.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the following construct:

```
(defvar objc-font-lock-test-setup-directory
  (if load-file-name
      (file-name-directory load-file-name)
   default-directory))
```

It works both when the file is loaded or when doing something like an `eval-buffer`.

Comment: Thanks, both ways seem to work, but I had to give the answer to legoscia for answering first

Comment: OK, fair enough!